# Edit smart group criteria resets Group(s) to Administrators

Tags: smartgroups

I just found this issue on the latest 4.6.21 release but was able to reproduce on 4.6.18 as well.

When I create a new smart group:

```
Search -> Advanced Search -> Choose any group but Administrators -> Create smart group
```

then in the next step I want to edit it:

```
Contacts -> Manage Groups -> Choose the one you just created -> Settings -> Edit smart group criteria -> On the top of the page Edit xyz smart group criteria
```

and I see Administrators Group there not the one I chose originally.

This seems to be a bug to me?
Can anyone confirm or test on previous releases?

Thanks

Comment: Replicated on 4.6 demo but does not occur on 4.7 demo. Could not find a corresponding issue in JIRA.

Comment: yep can confirm this happens on our 4.6 system too

Comment: Thanks everyone who confirmed. I have created an issue on Jira: [CRM-19433](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19433)